# Insert Into MySQL from Dynamic Array sent through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

## UPDATED Solution

I realised that sending this array should NOT be this complicated. I went back and revised my original jquery script to push() the [] items.

```
var seqImg = new Array();
    $('input[name="seqImg[]"]').each( function() {
        seqImg.push($(this).val());
    } );
```

With the ajax, I used an `data: {seqImg:seqImg}` with the additional configuration of `async:false` to ensure the sequence stayed in correct order.

In the PHP...

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO  unit_test(`unit_id`,`seq_img`) VALUES ";            

              $i=0;
              $seqImgs_count = count($seqImgs);

              //$data = $seqImgs_count;
              //echo $data;

              foreach($seqImgs as $item) {

                  $end = ($i == $seqImgs_count-1) ? ';' : ',';

                  $sql .= "('".$unit_id1."','".$item."')".$end;
```

It works!

## Original Message (for what its worth...)

I am trying to collect a set of sequences that are to be dynamically generated by the user.

So far, I've emulated [AustinAllover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840297/get-values-from-json-array-and-do-sql-insert). This seems to have gotten me close, but not quite there.

## The PHP

```
// Connect to the database
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    or die ('Error connecting to MySQL server.');


    if(isset($_POST["result"])){ 
        $json       =   trim($_POST['result']);
        $item_array =   json_decode($json,true);

        // Begin building the query
        // ------------------------
        $sql= "INSERT INTO  unit_test (`unit_id`,`seq_img`,`seq_desc`) VALUES ";            

        $i=0;
        $array_count = count($item_array);

            // ------------------------
            // NOTE: I've echo'd $array_count
            //...it is showing `1`
            //...but it is supposed to be 3
            // ------------------------

        $data = $array_count;
        echo $data;

        foreach($item_array as $item) {

            // Create comma or semi-colon       
            $end = ($i == $array_count) ? ';' : ',';

            // Build each row of data to insert
            $sql .= "('".$item['unit_id']."','".$item['array_seq_image']."','".$item['array_seq_desc']."')".$end;
            $i++;
                }
        mysqli_query($dbc,$sql)
            or die('Error with INSERT. '.$sql);

        mysqli_close($dbc);
```

## The Fiddle

The alert shares the `seq_array` sent via Ajax `data: {result:JSON.stringify(seq_array)}`, I've included the example Jquery/Ajax:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/8LcxhowL/)

## The Result

Jquery Alert is showing the array sent:

```
"{"0":{"unit_id":1","ajax_seq_image":"111","ajax_seq_desc":"sample1"},"1":{"unit_id":1","ajax_seq_image":"222","ajax_seq_desc":"sample2"},"2":{"unit_id":1","ajax_seq_image":"333","ajax_seq_desc":"sample3"}}"
```

Console is showing me the following result from the query attempt:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/cpardonc/public_html/mw/test_form_process2.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
Error with INSERT. INSERT INTO  unit_test (`unit_id`,`seq_img`,`seq_desc`) VALUES
```

Comment: plz paste the json_decoded $_POST['result']?

Comment: @Anish Here is the echo of `trim($_POST['result']`:
"\"{\"0\":{\"unit_id\":1\",\"ajax_seq_image\":\"111\",\"ajax_seq_desc\":\"sample 1\"},\"1\":{\"unit_id\":1\",\"ajax_seq_image\":\"222\",\"ajax_seq_desc\":\"sample 2\"},\"2\":{\"unit_id\":1\",\"ajax_seq_image\":\"333\",\"ajax_seq_desc\":\"sample 3\"}}\""<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/cpardonc/public_html/mw/test_form_process2.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
Error with INSERT. INSERT INTO unit_test (`unit_id`,`seq_img`,`seq_desc`) VALUES

Comment: the json string is not properly formated . seq_array += '"'+seq_order+'"'+':{"unit_id":"'+unit_id+'","'+seq_image+'":"'+si+'","'+seq_desc+'":"'+sd+'"}'+comma2;

Comment: Provide us with output of `echo $sql; exit;` inside your `foreach`.

Comment: @Anish I think you are right. I'm trying to create an array that sends the following new row(s):
 `{"unit_id[0]":1","ajax_seq_image[0]":"111","ajax_seq_desc[0]":"sample1"}`
 `{"unit_id[1]":1","ajax_seq_image[1]":"222","ajax_seq_desc[1]":"sample2"}`
 `{"unit_id[2]":1","ajax_seq_image[2]":"333","ajax_seq_desc[2]":"sample3"}`
...i think

Comment: @Anish you submitted an identical code to what I have?

Comment: Oh . I think you didnt saw my edit. After working the code which I pasted , what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

You json is not well formatted. You missed a " .

it should be like this

```
{"0":{"unit_id":"1","ajax_seq_image":"111","ajax_seq_desc":"sample1"},"1":{"unit_id":"1","ajax_seq_image":"222","ajax_seq_desc":"sample2"},"2":{"unit_id":"1","ajax_seq_image":"333","ajax_seq_desc":"sample3"}}
```

But it is like this.

```
{"0":{"unit_id":1","ajax_seq_image":"111","ajax_seq_desc":"sample1"},"1":{"unit_id":1","ajax_seq_image":"222","ajax_seq_desc":"sample2"},"2":{"unit_id":1","ajax_seq_image":"333","ajax_seq_desc":"sample3"}}
```

see the difference?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed the missing ". Still receiving same console message:

Comment: what is the output of $item_array after you made the change? what is output of var_dump($item_array);

Comment: var_dump($item_array) provided the following:
string(213) ""{"0":{"unit_id":"1","ajax_seq_image":"111","ajax_seq_desc":"sample 1"},"1":{"unit_id":"1","ajax_seq_image":"222","ajax_seq_desc":"sample 2"},"2":{"unit_id":"1","ajax_seq_image":"333","ajax_seq_desc":"sample 3"}}""

Comment: ok then there is wrong with $item_array =   json_decode($json,true); try this $item_array =   json_decode(trim($json,"\""),true);

Answer (score 0):

**In case you missed the UPDATED SOLUTION posted at the start of the original question...**
I realised that sending this array should NOT be this complicated. I went back and revised my original jquery script to push() the [] items.

```
var seqImg = new Array();
$('input[name="seqImg[]"]').each( function() {
    seqImg.push($(this).val());
} );
```

With the ajax, I used an `data: {seqImg:seqImg}` with the additional configuration of `async:false` to ensure the sequence stayed in correct order.

**In the PHP...**

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO  unit_test(`unit_id`,`seq_img`) VALUES ";            

          $i=0;
          $seqImgs_count = count($seqImgs);

          //$data = $seqImgs_count;
          //echo $data;

          foreach($seqImgs as $item) {

              $end = ($i == $seqImgs_count-1) ? ';' : ',';

              $sql .= "('".$unit_id1."','".$item."')".$end;
```

It works!